# How do I test dart NoSuchMethodError

Tags: dart, testing

How do i test for a class that some method doesn't exists `NoSuchMethodError` Exists?
something like the below example.

```dart
expect(1.leftShift(12), NoSuchMethodError);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test this like you would any other error. You can pass in a function that throws the error into `expect` and check that it throws the right error:

```dart
const dynamic x = 'hello';
expect(() => x.notAMethod(), throwsA(isA<NoSuchMethodError>()));
```

Note that you will need to make your receiver (the object you are calling the method on) to be `dynamic` to suppress the static error that would otherwise catch this error.

Comment: Thanks a lot. exactly what I was looking for <3